# How can I modify my procedural shadows to also show some of the walls?

Tags: 2d, libgdx, tilemap, fragment-shader, shadows

I'm rendering shadows in Libgdx with the method from [this tutorial](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/2D-Pixel-Perfect-Shadows). I think it's a nice and easy method.
I render all my shadows in a framebuffer, then invert it.

Before invert:

[image: Shadow Without Invert]

After Invert:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP 
#endif

varying vec2 vTexCoord0;
varying LOWP vec4 vColor;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main(void) {
    vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuseColor.rgb + vColor.rgb, vColor.a - diffuseColor.a);
}
```

[image: After Invert]

That's all working fine.

Now I want to show a bit of the walls. But I'm not sure how. I tried using the 
framebuffer with the lights, scale it a bit, and then draw the walls with blending.
But it's looking not very good:

[image: with wall sight]

Is there a better way?